# Ubuntu GUI problem

Tags: gnome, remote-desktop, xrdp

I have installed *xrdp* and *gnome* on Ubuntu 14. Now when I am trying to connect it using remote desktop, there is only this screen. How can I fix this problem? Thanks

[image: screenshot of the Remote Desktop connection window]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Here is what I did and it worked.

1. Install xfce4.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xfce4
   ```
2. Edit this file: `sudo nano /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh`

   Add the following lines at the end of the file (add #, then add the next line):

   ```
   #. /etc/X11/Xsession 
   . /usr/bin/startxfce4
   ```
3. Restart the service:

   ```
   sudo service xrdp restart
   ```

You should now have a desktop when you connect.